# How to bind a List to a Textbox in an ItemsControl

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, binding

I want to add some strings to a List (via button) and show it in an ItemsSource, but it doesn't work. Thats my code:

**XAML:**

```
<ItemsControl  ItemsSource="{Binding ListInfos, Mode=OneWay}">
<ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Grid>
            <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=., Mode=OneWay}" />
            ...
```

**VIEW-MODEL:**

```
private List<String> _listInfos = new List<String>();

public List<String> ListInfos
{
    get { return _listInfos; }
    set
    {
        _listInfos = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged("ListInfos");
    }
}

public void AddStringButton()
{
    ListInfos.Add("test");
}
```

The AddStringButton method works, but the property (set) of ListInfos doesn't fire and die GUI doesn't show the string test.

Comment: use `ObservableCollection<T>` instead of `List<T>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As dkozl said, you would need to use the ObservableCollection class, which provides notifications when the contents of the list changes. The only way the List PropertyChanged event will fire is if you set it to a new list instance.

Comment: Edit: Deleted the OP comment by mistake. Question was:
One more question. I need an ObservableCollection with Key and Value, do you know which element I should use?

I can't think of anything built into .NET that can do what you're looking for, so you will need to build a custom class to take care of it. 
Is there a particular reason why you need keys on the items in the collection? It will make binding to the properties a lot more difficult.